# UWP AudioGraph API - FrameOutputNode read bytes wrong

Tags: c#, windows, audio, uwp

I have a problem with the `FrameOutputNode` of the UWP Audio Graph API. I have a very simple graph that reads audio from a wav (PCM 16000Hz, 16 bit mono) file and sends it to the frame output node for processing. When processing, I need the audio to be in shorts (as they are in the raw bytes of the file). But as I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35026378/8170620) the data can only be read as floats.

Here is my code:

```
var encoding = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateWav(AudioEncodingQuality.Low);
encoding.Audio = AudioEncodingProperties.CreatePcm(16000, 1, 16);

AudioGraphSettings settings = new AudioGraphSettings(AudioRenderCategory.Media);
settings.EncodingProperties = encoding.Audio;
CreateAudioGraphResult result = await AudioGraph.CreateAsync(settings);
var graph = result.Graph;

var localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile file = await localFolder.GetFileAsync("audio.wav");

var fileInputNodeResult = await graph.CreateFileInputNodeAsync(file);
var fileInputNode = fileInputNodeResult.FileInputNode;

fileInputNode.FileCompleted += async (AudioFileInputNode sender, object args) =>
{
    graph.Stop();
}

frameOutputNode = graph.CreateFrameOutputNode(encoding.Audio);
fileInputNode.AddOutgoingConnection(frameOutputNode);

graph.QuantumStarted+= AudioGraph_QuantumStarted;
```

With the following `AudioGraph_QuantumStarted` event handler:

```
private void AudioGraph_QuantumStarted(AudioGraph sender, object args)
{
    AudioFrame frame = frameOutputNode.GetFrame();
    ProcessFrameOutput(frame);
}

unsafe private void ProcessFrameOutput(AudioFrame frame)
{
    AudioBuffer buffer = frame.LockBuffer(AudioBufferAccessMode.Read);
    IMemoryBufferReference reference = buffer.CreateReference();
    ((IMemoryBufferByteAccess)reference).GetBuffer(out byte* dataInBytes, out uint capacityInBytes);

    if (capacityInBytes > 0) {
        // Read the first 20 bytes 
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(dataInBytes[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The bytes I receive in the output are the following. Since the samples are returned as bytes of a float, I marked the sample boundary with a line.

```
0 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 184 | 0 0 128 184 | 0 0 0 184 ...
```

But when I read the actual bytes from the file with a byte reader:

```
FileStream fIn = new FileStream(@"/path/to/audio.wav", FileMode.Open);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fIn);
// Skip the first 44 bytes since they are header stuff
br.ReadBytes(44);
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
{
    Debug.WriteLine(br.ReadByte());
}
```

Then I get the actual bytes:

```
0 0 | 255 255 | 254 255 | 255 255 | 255 255 | 254 255 | 253 255 | 252 255 ...
```

Again I marked the individual samples (shorts -> two bytes) with a line.

As you can see the short bytes 255 255 somehow map to float bytes 0 0 0 184 as they reoccur. So what is that mapping? How can I retrieve the raw shorts from the floats? What do I need to do to actually read the wav file bytes?

Comment: What's the speechRecognitionNode from your code snippet? Can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?

Comment: Sorry it is the frameoutput node I created above, that was just a mistake in the code.

Comment: Yes I'll prepare a demo and give you the link.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/erksch/662772d6a90d6605c0368b964f937b5c
Here is a gist of a MainPage.xaml.cs that you can just copy into a fresh C# UWP project. You have to copy an audio file to the LocalState folder of the app. You can download an 16000Hz 16 bit Mono example audio here https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/raw/master/data/smoke_test/new-home-in-the-stars-16k.wav. The actual bytes of the file and the bytes the frame output node reads are printed to the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question was answered [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/issues/1196#issuecomment-622174708). Basically, the floats are the range of the shorts -32768 to 32767 converted to range -1 to 1 in float.

So given a float x in the buffer (use `(float*)dataInFloats = (float*)dataInBytes` to convert) you can calculate the corresponding short with:

```
f(x) = (65535 * x - 1) / 2
```